# Right hand operand of '&&' or '||' is an expression with possible side effects

Tags: c, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, qa-c

Code statement look like below:

```
if((temp1 == ID1) || (temp2 == (C_UINT16) ID2))
{

}
```

I am not sure why QAC is generating this warning. What will be the side effect & how to avoid this warning.

Details for QAC-help:

> The right hand operand of a logical && operator is only evaluated if
>   the left hand operand evaluates to 1 ("true"). The right hand operand
>   of a logical || operator is only evaluated if the left hand operand
>   evaluates to 0 ("false").
>
> Because of this behaviour, confusion can arise if the right hand
>   operand of either of these operators generates side effects. Message
>   3415 is generated to identify such a situation.
>
> Side effects occur when an expression:

1. accesses a volatile object
2. executes an increment, decrement, assignment or compound assignment
   operation
3. performs I/O  or
4. calls a function which does any of the above

> However QAC assumes that side effects occur whenever a function is
>   called, unless the function has specifically been identified as being
>   free from side effects by a #pragma statement of the form:

```
#pragma PRQA_NO_SIDE_EFFECTS funcname
```

Answer (score 0):

While looking at variable temp1 & temp2. I got to know it is declared as volatile. After changing the variable to the normal non-volatile, the warning is not observed. It was level 4 warning in QAC.

Reference:
https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/68666-strange-side-effects.html

Another way to resolve the error to read the volatile variable again before performing the operation again.